# Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org - flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

[image]When i run project with android emulator in Macbook, show  this error Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org

Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.